# Other properties appear in Apache PDFBox custom properties

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using **commons-logging-1.2.jar** and **fontbox-2.0.27.jar**
For some reason, some value like "CreationDate", "ModDate" and "Title" was detected in my custom properties but i didn't declare it whatsoever or even added it. I use if else statement to prevent them adding into arraylist. Does anyone know what is the root cause or how to solve it?

**My code...**

```
public List<String[]> readPDFProperties(String fileName, String filePath) {
        System.out.println("PDF");
        System.out.println(fileName);
        List<String[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            PDDocumentInformation pdDocumentInformation = pdDocument.getDocumentInformation();
            Set<String> set = pdDocumentInformation.getMetadataKeys();
            Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String value = iterator.next().trim();
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Author") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("CreationDate") ||
                        value.equalsIgnoreCase("Creator") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("ModDate") ||
                        value.equalsIgnoreCase("Title") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("Trapped") ||
                        value.equalsIgnoreCase("Producer") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("Subject") ||
                        value.equalsIgnoreCase("Keywords") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("Config File")) {
                } else {
                    String creationDate = pdDocumentInformation.getCreationDate().getTime().toString() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCreationDate().getTime().toString() : "";
                    String modifiedDate = pdDocumentInformation.getModificationDate().getTime().toString() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getModificationDate().getTime().toString() : "";
                    String[] arr = new String[14];

                    arr[0] = fileName;
                    arr[1] = pdDocumentInformation.getTitle() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getTitle() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Title") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Title") : "";
                    arr[2] = pdDocumentInformation.getSubject() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getSubject() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Subject") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Subject") : "";
                    arr[3] = pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Author") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Author") : "";
                    arr[4] = "";
                    arr[5] = "";
                    arr[6] = "";
                    arr[7] = pdDocumentInformation.getKeywords() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getKeywords() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Keywords") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Keywords") : "";
                    arr[8] = ""; //9

                    arr[9] = value != null ? value : "";
                    arr[10] = pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString(value) != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString(value) : "";

                    arr[11] = creationDate;
                    arr[12] = modifiedDate;
                    arr[13] = ""; //3
                    arrList.add(arr);
                }
            }

            if (arrList.size() == 0) {
                String creationDate = pdDocumentInformation.getCreationDate().getTime().toString() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCreationDate().getTime().toString() : "";
                String modifiedDate = pdDocumentInformation.getModificationDate().getTime().toString() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getModificationDate().getTime().toString() : "";
                String[] arr = new String[14];

                arr[0] = fileName;
                arr[1] = pdDocumentInformation.getTitle() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getTitle() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Title") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Title") : "";
                arr[2] = pdDocumentInformation.getSubject() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getSubject() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Subject") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Subject") : "";
                arr[3] = pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Author") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Author") : "";
                arr[4] = "";
                arr[5] = "";
                arr[6] = "";
                arr[7] = pdDocumentInformation.getKeywords() != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getKeywords() : pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Keywords") != null ? pdDocumentInformation.getCOSObject().getString("Keywords") : "";
                arr[8] = ""; //9

                arr[9] = "";
                arr[10] = "";

                arr[11] = creationDate;
                arr[12] = modifiedDate;
                arr[13] = ""; //3
                arrList.add(arr);
            }
            pdDocument.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrList;
    }
```

**CSV**
[image]

Expecting a solution or a reason

Comment: Surprise! There are 2 sets of metadata, the second one is the XMP stuff https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ExtractMetadata.java?view=markup

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I read the codes from the link you gave and tried with metadata but it didn't work. The error i'm getting was "org.apache.xmpbox.xml.XmpParsingException: Cannot find a definition for the namespace http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/
". Thus, I'm stuck with PDDocumentInformation. I also check my pdf versions with veraPDF and they were PDF/A-1B (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4961)

Comment: I had a look at the pdf properties.
File>Properties>Custom
It have exactly all the property which are test1-test7 and that's all. It also have a note...
"You can add custom properties to this document. Each custom property requires a unique name, which must not be one of the standard property names Title, Author, Subject, Keywords, Creator, Producer, CreationDate, ModDate and Trapped."

Comment: This is a weakness of xmpbox. You can use JempBox of PDFBox 1.8.17. Sadly I don't have any quick examples, you could look into the tika source code. Or in the test cases of the jempbox source code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but i will remain it this way first and ensure i exclude the standard property name due to some circumstances 